# In a stream of objects - how do I filter out unique elements of the highest priority?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-stream

I have a problem that feels like it should be simple to solve using java streams but so far I been unsuccessful (at least in any simple way).
I have a stream of objects

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}
List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Eric", 10),
            new Person("Eric", 20),
            new Person("Anna", 20),
            new Person("John", 20),
            new Person("Mary", 5),
            new Person("Mary", 20),
            new Person("Mary", 10));
```

How would I go about manipulating this list using streams so I would end up with a list (or any other collection) containing each person (Eric, Anna, John and Mary) together with their highest age.

```
[Person{name='Eric', age=20}, Person{name='Anna', age=20}, Person{name='John', age=20}, Person{name='Mary', age=20}]
```

The obvious would be to implement Equals/Hash correctly but with that I only come up with the first occurance of each person. Ive also looked at treeset and comparators but without success.
What would be the most elegant way to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any explicit constructor with the name and age arguments in the `Person` class (so there can't be an expression like `new Person("Eric", 10)`).

Comment: Sorry, I removed it for brevity - I probably should have pointed that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to add `hashCode()` and `equals()` to `Person` class than you probably have to map by the `String` name. You can use `Collectors.groupingBy`, `Collectors.mapping` and `Collectors.maxBy` to find the max age:

```
Map<String, Optional<Integer>> collect = personList.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Person::getName, 
                mapping(Person::getAge, maxBy(Integer::compare))));
```

or as pointed out by Holger:

```
Map<String, Integer> collect = personList.stream()
    .collect(toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAge, Math::max));
```

which will create:

```
{Eric=Optional[20], John=Optional[20], Mary=Optional[20], Anna=Optional[20]}
```

Comment: Thanks - never tried those functions. Its not that I didnt want to add `hashCode()` and `equals()` but rather that I didnt see how to implement them correctly. I could only come up with using both 'name' and 'age' where I got a set of all elements or using just 'name' where I got all names but with the first instance of age `[Person{name='Eric', age=10}, Person{name='Anna', age=20}, Person{name='John', age=20}, Person{name='Mary', age=5}].
`

Comment: Well, adding name based `hashCode()` and `equals()` to `Person`, just for the sake of a single particular operation, wouldn’t be the right thing anyway. After all `Person("Eric", 10)` and `Person("Eric", 20)` are not the same person. So *grouping by name* when needed, is the right approach. Alternatively, `toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAge, Math::max)`

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use `toMap` based on name as the `key` (for uniqueness as I understand from the question) and collect `Person` as `value`s while merging based on the `age` as a priority. This could be achieved as:

```
Collection<Person> personWithAgeAsPriority = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity(), // name as key and person as values
                BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge)))) // compare age and choose
        .values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a more conventional approach to achieve this:

> ```
> public class TestClass {
>
>   public static void addToMap(Map<String, Integer> map, String name, Integer age){
>
>       if(map.get(name) == null || map.get(name) < age)
>           map.put(name, age);
>
>           }
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
>       addToMap(map, "Eric", 10);
>       addToMap(map, "Eric", 20);
>       addToMap(map, "Anna", 20);
>       addToMap(map, "John", 20);
>       addToMap(map, "Mary", 5);
>       addToMap(map, "Mary", 30);
>       addToMap(map, "Mary", 10);
>
>       for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
>           System.out.println("[" + entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue() + "]");
>   }
> ```

You can make changes to this code to handle the object of Person class. Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that’s easiest to read is one that uses two steps:

```
int maxAge =
    personList.stream().mapToInt(p -> p.age).max().getAsInt();

Collection<Person> oldestPersons =
    personList.stream().filter(p -> p.age == maxAge).collect(
        Collectors.toList());
```

If you insist on doing it in one pass, I would group the persons by age into a TreeMap, and use that TreeMap’s highest entry (that is, the entry corresponding to the highest age):

```
Collection<Person> oldestPersons =
    personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.age,
        TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList())).lastEntry().getValue();
```

Comment: It might be just coincidence that the oldest persons of each name have the same age.

Comment: Yes, Im sorry if that was unclear. In the fake example that I tried to create the intention was to get the each name with the oldes age (In my realcase scenario its actually the objects with the latest versions). Thanks for the effort still.